# Касательно нумизматики и не только

Tags: грамотная-речь

В былые времена о потертой монете или банкноте говорили "в плохом состоянии". Нынче вошло в моду слово "сохранность". А не совсем грамотные нумизматы часто говорят о том же, используя слово "качество". 
Как правильнее, сохранность, или состояние? Или оба варианта имеют право сосуществовать?

Answer (score 1):

Однажды мне вздумалось продать монету доновоэрную. Описываю её крутому нумизмату по телефону. Прерывает (и прощается): "Понятно. Состояние неколлекционное".

Википедия: [состояние монет](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

> Сначала различали очень небольшое число градаций состояния (или
>   степеней сохранности) монет...

Подробнее о *Good, Very Good, Fine, Very Fine, Extremely Fine, Uncirculated* - по ссылке.